# Syncing the Outlook Web App calendar with the one in Windows Live Mail

Tags: windows-7, email, windows-live-mail, outlook-web-access

I have already entered all my classes for the year into the Windows Live Mail calendar, but my college uses Outlook web app. I want to be able to schedule meetings with the Outlook web app, but I don't want to have to manually transfer all my classes to its calendar. On top of that, I prefer the UI of Windows Live/ Windows Live Mail's calendar, hence the desire to sync rather than transfer. How might I go about this?

I am running Windows Live Mail Version 2011 (Build 15.4.3555.0308) & my college is using Outlook Web App Premium version 14.2.298.4.

I have tried installing Outlook Connector, but I am dubious regarding its success. It only takes about a second or two to install what ends up being updates to Windows Live Mail (which *supposedly* contains, among other things, Outlook Connector); after this supposed installation is complete, I still find no means of linking hotmail with outlook web app. I should mention that I would also like to sync email sending/receiving. POP, IMAP & SMTP settings are not available for Outlook web app.

Addendum: Windows Live seems to want me to update far too often; I've upgraded twice already since 9:00AM CDT (currently 12:16PM) and now its asking a third time. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried installing Outlook Connector on both the computer with Windows Live Mail & Outlook 2010 (which I discovered was available just today) with no luck.  I also tried linking both Hotmail & Gmail to Outlook 2010 via POP & SMTP, this also failed. From this I conclude that my college seeks to prevent their servers from being overwhelmed with the personal emails of all their students.